# Getting total unread notification count in Tizen and opening notification app on Gear 2

Tags: notifications, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to add a notifications feature to my watchface.
I want to get total count of notifications on the Samsung Gear 2 and then when a specific areais clicked I would like to take the user to the "Notifications" app of the Samsung Gear.

Is this possible ?
How ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Notification Web API is not available in wearable SDK. So you can't.

Comment: ok. what about opening the local notifications app ? is it possible to open that app when a screen area is clicked ?

Comment: where can I find documentation on how to use this function ?

Comment: I want to launch "com.samsung.wnotification2". How ?

Comment: anybody who could help me to launch this ?

Comment: @m.wasowski regarding Gear S, you are simply not correct.

Answer (score 0):

To launch application you have to know ID. There is example in documentation:

```
tizen.application.launch(ApplicationId id, optional SuccessCallback? successCallback, optional ErrorCallback? errorCallback);
```

or:

```
tizen.application.launchAppControl(
     appControl,
     appId,
     function() {console.log("launch application control succeed"); },
    function(e) {console.log("launch application control failed. reason: " + e.message); },
    appControlReplyCallback );
```

You can find information in Tizen SDK help:
API References > Device API Reference > Application
and
Programming Guide > Device API Guides > Application Guides

You need the permission: http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch

Answer (score 0):

> > I want to launch "com.samsung.wnotification2". How ? 
> >     anybody who could help me to launch this ?

I hope you've found an answer already, though let me post an answer as I am stumbling into your question for fifth time ;)

```
var notificationsAppId = "com.samsung.wnotification2";

tizen.application.launch(notificationsAppId, function() {
    console.log("launch success");
}, function() {
    console.log("launch failed");
});
```

Please also take into account that this method of calling notifications screen will not work for Gear S - Samsung disabled ability to launch the "com.samsung.wnotification2" (though, if you try, the launch request will not indicate failure!)